# Publish EXE desktop app for Microsoft store

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps

I have an app created by `C++` and `Visual Studio 2015`. It packed by `Inno Setup` and has "exe" format.
I want to publish this app on Microsoft Store. Is it possible?
I have developer account but can not upload exe file - too many errors.
Can I use VS 2015 or need upgrade to 2019?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible now. Just select right product type.

[image]

In my case product was added many years ago and has "MSIX or PWA app" type.